# Message Format or Description

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Is there a way we can know the description of the data that is logged for each topic ?

For example the data logged to the topic /navsat/fix contains altitude ,longitude and latitude and also many other fields. Is there a way we can understand what these other fields are ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189402/message-format-or-description/) by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean like knowing the rest of the fields of that message type? that can be done through `rosmsg show <message>`, as described here [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg). If you wish to know the message type of the topic, the you can run `rostopic type <topic>`, or in your case, `rostopic type /navsat/fix`.

The source .msg file will also often contain documentation describing each field.

---

Originally posted by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) with karma: 301 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19964/naz/) on 2014-08-07**:
Thank you , where exactly is the source .msg file for each datatype , I need a detailed description of different datatypes.

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-07**:
Each message type is specified by its package name and then the message name, e.g, geometry_msgs/Pose refers to Pose.msg in the geometry_msgs package. Hence navigating to the package first and looking for the .msg file should be fruitful. You can learn more here http://wiki.ros.org/Messages